# Test for a program that receives input from keyboard

Tags: python, c, bash, testing, automated-tests

I have done a program that receives input from the terminal with the readline function in c (https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/basics-of-using-the-readline-library/), readline saves keyboard input from the terminal (basically a read for the stdin) and saves it inside a buffer.
Imagine, when my program is executed, it just prints a message on the screen like: *Enter a command: * and I can write a bash command and it's going to execute it (Just like bash).
I wanted to do a test (In python, c++ or bash) that is going to start the program, and writes into the readline and check is output compared to bash, does anyone knows a way to do it?

Comment: What kind of "test" do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an initial bash script that randomizes input with some properties:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
    input=$(echo {A..Z} {a..z} | tr ' ' "\n" | shuf | xargs | tr -d ' ' | cut -b 1-18)
    echo ${input}
    /path/to/your_program < ${input}
done
```

You can add characters, make the input shorter etc.

Answer (score 0):

### [I/O Redirection](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php)

You can find many ways to do what you need using **[I/O Redirection](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php)** for example:

You can **pipe** the output of `echo` command to be an input for your program.

run this in your terminal:

```
echo " *the input you want to your program* " | ./program_excecutable_path
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to grab the input in python (I suggest you use the [input()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) function), store it in a variable, then print it out in the terminal using [print()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).